# What is correct way to re-render one component from another [Vue.js]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have `select`:

```
  <select @change="getValuesFromDate($event)">
                        <option value="1">Last 24 hours</option>
                        <option value="7">Last7 days</option>
                        <option value="30">Last 30 days</option>
                        <option>Custom date</option>
                    </select>
```

and chart component

```
                          <graph-component
                                :key="graphKey"
                                v-bind="measurement"
                                :value="valueOfMeasurement(measurement)"
                                :time_date="dateOfMeasurement()"
                            ></graph-component>
```

Function `getValuesFromDate($event)` calls API:

```
   getValuesFromDate(event) {
        let apiLink ="https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1111111/feeds.json?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXX&days=" +event.target.value +"&round=2&average=";
        let preferableSize = 0;
        if (event.target.value == 1) {
            preferableSize = 60;
        } else {
            preferableSize = 1440;
        }
        try {
            axios
                .get(apiLink + preferableSize, {
                    withCredentials: false
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.message = response.data;
                });
            this.graphKey+= 1;
        } catch (error) {}
    }
```

When I change select (and call this function) I re-render `graph-component` by changing it key, and it works just fine.
What is better and more correct way to do this or this one is fine enough?

Comment: That seems like an acceptable way of rerendering the component, but why is that needed?

Comment: so my graphs get redrawn with new values when I change date period with select

Comment: Doesn't the graph redraw if the `:value` changes? Isn't `valueOfMeasurement` reactive?

Comment: It is not possible to accurately answer your question without adding more details/code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Lube this is the best way to force a re-render of a component. I've needed to do the same for graph components in the past when my data changes.

There's a great article I've linked to below that explains the various ways of forcing a re-render, but ultimately the best way is adding a `:key` property to your component and updating that key whenever you need a re-render.

Article can be found [here](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/).